# Jenkins pipeline with .NET core app, MSTest, and Cake script

Tags: jenkins, asp.net-core, mstest, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins pipeline which calls a Cake build script on a .NET core web application with MSTest test projects.

My Jenkinsfile is very simple at the moment

```
pipeline {   
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('BuildAndTest') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
                bat 'powershell.exe -file ./build.ps1 -Configuration Debug -Target Test  -ScriptArgs \'-Name=<my solution name>\''
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
        always {
            deleteDir()
        }
    }
}
```

The targets in my build.cake script that are being executed are GitVersion, RestoreNugetPackages, Build, Test.

When I run the Cake build at a command prompt, using the exact same command from the bat line in the Jenkinsfile above, from the Jenkins workspace folder where the code is checked out to, the build completes successfully. When I trigger the build from Jenkins, all steps succeed except the Test step. It fails with several 'The type or namespace name ... could not be found' errors. Some of those that are not found are System, System.String, TestClassAttribute.

It looks like a nuget restore problem specifically on the unit test projects, but one of the first steps in the Cake script is RestoreNugetPackages and the Jenkins console output during that step shows that it restored the nuget packages for the unit test projects, so all indications are that the nuget restore worked fine.

Again, running the entire script manually from a command prompt works, but fails when triggered via Jenkins. Anyone else running a similar setup that has run into this and solved it? I have trying to figure this out for a few days now.

Below is some output from the Jenkins build....

```
========================================
RestoreNugetPackages
========================================
Executing task: RestoreNugetPackages
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.1.1012.6693' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\bin'.
Restoring packages for C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\src\mydotnetcore.web.application\mydotnetcore.web.application.csproj...
Restoring packages for C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj...
Committing restore...
Generating MSBuild file C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\obj\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj.nuget.g.props.
Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\obj\project.assets.json
Restore completed in 8.5 sec for C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj.
Committing restore...
Generating MSBuild file C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\src\mydotnetcore.web.application\obj\mydotnetcore.web.application.csproj.nuget.g.props.
Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\src\mydotnetcore.web.application\obj\project.assets.json
Restore completed in 9.95 sec for C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\src\mydotnetcore.web.application\mydotnetcore.web.application.csproj.

NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
    C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config

Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
Finished executing task: RestoreNugetPackages


========================================
Test
========================================
Executing task: Test
Build started, please wait...
C:\Windows\TEMP\.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,20): error CS0400: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.AssemblyInfo.cs(14,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.AssemblyInfo.cs(15,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.AssemblyInfo.cs(16,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.AssemblyInfo.cs(17,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.AssemblyInfo.cs(18,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.AssemblyInfo.cs(19,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.AssemblyInfo.cs(20,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.AssemblyInfo.cs(21,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
C:\Windows\TEMP\.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,71): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
C:\Windows\TEMP\.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,99): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FrameworkDisplayName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
C:\Windows\TEMP\.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,122): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.AssemblyInfo.cs(14,55): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.AssemblyInfo.cs(15,61): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.AssemblyInfo.cs(16,59): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.AssemblyInfo.cs(17,59): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.AssemblyInfo.cs(18,68): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.AssemblyInfo.cs(19,55): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.AssemblyInfo.cs(20,53): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.AssemblyInfo.cs(21,55): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
UnitTest1.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
UnitTest1.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
C:\Windows\TEMP\.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
C:\Windows\TEMP\.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.AssemblyInfo.cs(11,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.AssemblyInfo.cs(12,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
UnitTest1.cs(6,6): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
UnitTest1.cs(6,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestClassAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
UnitTest1.cs(6,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
UnitTest1.cs(7,18): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
UnitTest1.cs(10,16): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
UnitTest1.cs(9,10): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
UnitTest1.cs(9,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestMethodAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
UnitTest1.cs(9,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestMethod' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (    x86)\Jenkins\workspace\mydotnetcore.web.application.release-1.0.0\tests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests\mydotnetcore.web.application.UnitTests.csproj]
An error occurred when executing task 'Test'.
Error: .NET Core CLI: Process returned an error (exit code 1).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer and it was related to restoring NuGet packages.

In my original Cake build I had a step named "RestoreNugetPackages that looked like this

```
Task("RestoreNugetPackages")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        NuGetRestore(name + ".sln", new NuGetRestoreSettings());
    });
```

This would be the correct way to restore NuGet packages for a non-.Net Core application. For a .Net Core application, it should look like this

```
Task("RestoreNugetPackages")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        DotNetCoreRestore(name + ".sln");
    });
```

Now, the NuGet packages are restored correctly and my tests run as expected.